# How to send value as parameter to model in codeigniter to get data?

Tags: codeigniter

I am new in **codeigniter**.
Currently working in e-commerce site I want to send the `category_id` as parameter to bring product data.
I want to know the steps to detail and Thanks

This is my model:

```
( function get_category(){ $query = $this->db->query("SELECT a.category_id,a.category_name from ci_intro.categories a order by a.category_id"); return $query->result(); } function get_product($id){ $q = $this->db->query('select * from products where category_id = $id'); if($q->num_rows() > 0){ foreach ($q->result() as $row) { $data[] = $row; } return $data; } } )
```

and this is my controller

```
( public function services() { $this->load->model("get_db"); $data['results'] = $this->get_db->get_category(); $id=$this->input->post('id'); $data['cat_id'] = $this->get_db->get_product($id); $this->load->view("view_header"); $this->load->view("view_nav"); $this->load->view("content_portfolio",$data); $this->load->view("site_footer"); } )
```

Comment: Show your attempts what you have tried so far.

Comment: ( function  get_category(){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT a.category_id,a.category_name from   ci_intro.categories a order by a.category_id");
        return $query->result();
    }
    function  get_product($id){
                        
    $q = $this->db->query('select * from products where category_id = $id');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach ($q->result() as $row)
    {
        $data[] = $row;

        }
    return $data;
}
    
    } )

Comment: and this is my controller (  public function services() {
            $this->load->model("get_db");
            $data['results'] = $this->get_db->get_category();
            $id=$this->input->post('id');
            $data['cat_id'] = $this->get_db->get_product($id);
            $this->load->view("view_header");
            $this->load->view("view_nav");
            $this->load->view("content_portfolio",$data);
            $this->load->view("site_footer");

            
        } )

Comment: Please edit your own question in order to update code/items

Answer (score 0):

You get category_id in model as $_GET['category_id'] or $_REQUEST['category_id'] in model also .

Comment: please give me an example

Comment: I have given you the full example see below @sbycrims

Comment: Yes above example you send your category_id in model..
        $category_id=$this->input->post('category_id');
        $data['records']= $this->services_model->getData($category_id);

oterwise you get category_id in model also..

 class Services_model extends CI_Model {

function getUser() {
$id=$this->input->post('category_id');
    $q = $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach ($q->result() as $row)
    {
        $data[] = $row;

        }
    return $data;
}
}
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        $this->load->model('services_model');
       $id=$this->input->post('id');
        $data['records']= $this->services_model->getData($id);


        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

    }

 }
```

this is your controller example
and this is mlodel for you

```
 class Services_model extends CI_Model {

function getUser($id) {
    $q = $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach ($q->result() as $row)
    {
        $data[] = $row;

        }
    return $data;
}
}
 }
```

you can see various crud example and their website for further details

Answer (score 0):

Your category should be the drop downlist. on change event the id will be pass through ajax like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#category").change(function(){

                 /*dropdown post */
                $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/services/getproducts",    
                data: {catid: $(this).val()},
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){

                    $("#product").html(data);
                }

                });

            });

}
```

get prducts will be the function in services controller class you can get the category id using the

```
  $this->input->post('catid');
```

Comment: my category in a side menu not in a drop down list